# How to install loadable kernel module on android

Tags: android, kernel-module, busybox, android-source

I would like to install a loadable kernel module on android, but the module version is different than the kernel version of android.

I got the version magic mismatch error when using insmod.

So i use the modprobe (busybox v1.19.4) with -force version option, but modprobe keep telling me module not found.

Which location should i put the module in?

Comment: anyone can help? i stuck on this for few days..

Answer (score 0):

modprobe looks modules in /lib/modules/[version]/... So if your module version magic doesn't match the kernel, then it won't work.

I would rebuild the module using MODULE_VERSION macro and load it again